# Using two functions with table

Tags: jquery, function

I made a little listview widget which uses a table and assigned a function to its rows like:

```
$("tr",myTable).bind("click",function(){
    selectRow($(this));
});
```

I now would like to apply another function called deleteRow, but **only** to each row's last cell:

```
$("td:last-child",myTable).bind("click",function(){
    deleteRow($(this));
});
```

My question: when clicking the last cell for deleting a row, I don't want the selectRow function to be fired - how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the `click` from [bubbling up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to the `<tr>`, like this:

```
$("td:last-child",myTable).bind("click",function(e){
    deleteRow($(this));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Since your other click handler is on the `<tr>`, it won't fire, since you stopped it from bubbling up using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: thanks that helped :) i also found out that adding "return false" also seems stopping the bubbling-up, but not sure if it works the same as stopPropagation.

Comment: @Fuxi - It does, it triggers `stopPropgation()` *and* `preventDefault()` under the covers :)